# jQuery Form plugin - how to make ajaxForm() "live"?

Tags: jquery, forms, partial-views

So I'm turning an "edit" form into an ajaxForm with the following:

```
$('#reviewForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function (response) {
        $('#bookReview').html(response);
    }
});
```

This returns the same form, that can be edited again, if necessary.  The second form submission, however, no longer has the ajaxForm() attached to it, which makes sense.

How do I make sure this form is always an ajaxForm, no matter how many submissions have taken place, similar to how the live() function works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either include the `ajaxForm` call in the response like:

```
<!-- the html for the form -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#reviewForm').ajaxForm();
</script>
```

or you could do it as part of the success function:

```
function ajaxify(response, status, xhr, form){
   var review = $('#bookReview').html(response);
   $('form#reviewForm', review).ajaxForm({
      'success': ajaxify
   });
}

$('#reviewForm').ajaxForm({
   'success': ajaxify
});
```

I recommend the latter.

Comment: Hmmm, with that second one, isn't it missing some info. on the end?  It's like a never-ending redundancy, isn't it?

Comment: Oh i see what youre saying... well you could just make it another function ... ill update

Comment: My brain is in knots.  Where do the 4 parameters come from?  Javascript is totally foreign to me.  Thanks.

Comment: those paramters are always passed to the succes function for `ajaxForm`... see the docs: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object

Comment: Getting an error under the second "var": "Expected identifier or string"

Comment: Uh oh, if you're an idiot, what does that make me?  :-o
Thanks for all the help.  Any recommendations on how to learn this frustrating client-side junk?

Comment: i honestly dont remember how i picked up JS... bu tif i had to do it again and was starting from scratch i would find some resources on core js, specifically scope evaluation, the DOM, anonymous objects, closures, etc.

Comment: I've got the old Rhino book, that I haven't looked at in ages. Maybe I'll dust that one off.  Thanks.

Comment: IMO, delegating a click call to the first non-dynamic parent of "ajaxified" object  would be more readable and generally more reliable. You won't have to read through several codes to understand what is happening.

Comment: A better solution exists now, consisting of setting "delegation" to true

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#myFormId').live('submit', function() {
    // submit the form
    $(this).ajaxSubmit();
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation
    return false;
});
```

Sligtly modified example for ajaxSubmit from http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api.

Answer (score 8):

From the documentation :

**delegation**

true to enable support for event delegation requires jQuery v1.7+

```
// prepare all existing and future forms for ajax submission
$('form').ajaxForm({
     delegation: true
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the documentation where you found this? I searched at http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/ and there was no even a word `delegation`

Comment: Really easy solution, worked well for me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('#reviewForm').live('submit', function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        success:function(){
            $('#bookReview').html(response);
        },
        resetForm:true
    });
    return false;
});
```